# QString and some Qt classes are recognized as incomplete types

Tags: c++, qt

My code looks like this:

**a.h**

```
#include <QString>

namespace foo {
  QString bar(QString a);
}
```

**a.cc**

```
#include "a.h"

namespace foo {
  QString bar(QString a) { return QString(); } 
}
```

The issue is in a.cc, `QString` might be taken as `foo::QString`, thus results in incomplete type compilation error, 'cause we didn't and never want to define a `QString` class in `foo` namespace.

Note that I have CMakeLists.txt containing below lines:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS widgets REQUIRED)
set(Qt_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(a Qt_LIBRARIES)
```

Any idea? Thanks!

---

Kuba Ober have pointed my problem exactly.

Actually I have a header file with 500 lines code. Say **a.h** looks like this

[image: a.h]

Note that the braces for foo is not closed. While due to too much lines and the compiler (VS2013) ***doesn't*** complaint it with red underscores, I just didn't detect it.

Then in a.cc, we have code like this
[image: a.cc]

'Cause we include a.h in a.cc, even the `std` is wrapped under the `suri` namespace. Thus the `QString` might be wrapped under `suri` too, resulting in `recognized as incomplete type` compilation error.

This is the whole story. Thank you, guys!

Comment: Do you get an error saying that the "#include <QString>" cannot be found? What happens if you try "#include <QtCore/QString>" ?

Comment: The problem has been found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show is correct. The following demonstrates that there's no problem with such code. According to the standard, there's no way `QString` used here would be ambiguous: there's only one namespace visible from each point of use where that identifier exists.

```
// main.cpp
#include <QString>

namespace foo {
  QString bar(QString a);
  QString bar(QString) { return QString(); }
}

int main() {}
```

Whatever is the source of your problem, it isn't what you're showing to us. At the very least, you have a mistake somewhere that declares a `foo::QString` identifier, or declares `QString` in another visible namespace and makes the lookup ambiguous. Perhaps you even suffer from [the most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/1329652), but in reverse (you meant a function, but got a member named `QString` instead)?

A bug that reproduces a similar problem reads:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QString>

namespace foo {
  QString bar(QString a);
  int QString(); // BUG: introduce foo::QString as an identifier

  // Doesn't compile since QString is ambiguous
  QString bar(QString) { return QString(); }
  // Compiles OK, indicates presence of the BUG
  ::QString bar(::QString) { return ::QString(); }
}

int main() {}
```

You could also be inadvertently wrapping Qt includes into a namespace, e.g. on my particular platform (OS X 10.9), the following code produces the exact same error as you see:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class QString;
namespace z {
#include <QString>
}

namespace foo {
  QString bar(QString a);
  QString bar(QString) { return QString(); }
}

int main() {}
```

Compiler output:

```
../test2/main.cpp:15:11: error: incomplete result type 'QString' in function definition
  QString bar(QString) { return QString(); }
          ^
../test2/main.cpp:8:7: note: forward declaration of 'QString'
class QString;
      ^
../test2/main.cpp:15:22: error: variable has incomplete type 'QString'
  QString bar(QString) { return QString(); }
                     ^
../test2/main.cpp:8:7: note: forward declaration of 'QString'
class QString;
      ^
../test2/main.cpp:15:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'QString'
  QString bar(QString) { return QString(); }
                                ^~~~~~~~~
../test2/main.cpp:8:7: note: forward declaration of 'QString'
class QString;
      ^
3 errors generated.
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I've corrected the typo in my question. Actually I'm porting an old prj from Qt4 to Qt5. The reason I did not show the whole code is it's too large and classified in some degree. Sorry for not describing my question detailedly.

Comment: @StephenW It's your job to produce a minimal test case that reproduces the issue. Minimization from large code bases is an essential skill and without it your questions will suffer. It's also a skill necessary for efficient debugging of your own code.

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right. It's my job to produce a minimal test case the reproduces the issues. And you have pointed my problem too. Thank you!